# SQL result from table a but name from table b

Tags: mysql, sql

My request is quiet simple however I can't find it (maybe I can't goolge correctly).
I have Table A and Table B

Table A:

| ID | length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 45 |
| 2 | 20 |

and Table B

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | orange |

I want to get the sum of all lengths of Table A with unique ID but with Table B's names

| Name | length |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 50 |
| orange | 65 |

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    sum(a.length),
    (
        SELECT
            a.id, b.names, a.length
        FROM a
        INNER JOIN b ON (a.id= b.id)
    )
FROM a
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

I have a feeling i made it more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: JOIN then group and sum. `SELECT b.name, SUM(a.length) FROM a JOIN b USING (id) GROUP BY 1`.

Comment: "I tried the following" - and what happened? was that wrong or insufficient, and if so how?

Comment: @underscore_d *and what happened?* Of course, "subquery returns more than one row".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT b.[name],
    SUM(a.[length]) [length]
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY b.[name]
ORDER BY b.[name]
```

Comment: @uelf1 . . . I'm surprised that you accepted an answer that is syntactically incorrect for your database.  In any case, you need to remove the square braces.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TableB.name, sum(TableA.length)
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID=TableB.ID
GROUP BY TableB.name;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.